# Why declare (some) Spring-Beans

Tags: spring

I have got a small question about Spring-Beans and the difference to JavaEE: 
Why do I have to define some Beans in Spring in the Configuration (i.e. frome some other external libs) and in JavaEE not?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no small question.

JavaEE makes the assumption you've a got a container providing services in a standard way. You run your application in an application server that implements some or all of the APIs described in a particular version of the specification. You rely on the container and use it as it is supposed to work: Servlets, JSP, transaction management, JPA, CDI, authentication and authorization...

Spring is a different beast born mostly on the rout of EJB 2 in early 200x. It first showed you didn't need a full container (meaning you could do the data tier differently) and could benefit from dependency injection (DI). In the beginning, Spring was all about DI being done through XML files. These are the configuration files you're mentioning. Then came the different sub-projects of Spring: Spring Integration, Spring Web Services, Spring Data, Spring Boot... and the competition functionality-wise with JavaEE. EJB 2 was dropped in favor of the very Hibernate-inspired EJB 3. Annotations became favored of configuration files, etc. This was a very organic process, where good ideas strived to become better. Still configuration was here one way or another: in XML files, in annotations scattered in the components classes, in classes dedicated to configuration... This can be viewed as the downside of Spring, but this complexity allows you to integrate with a tremendous amounts of libs and middlewares and shape the application the way you see it.

JavaEE and Spring have become competitors over the years, with JavaEE lately taking some of the great ideas of Spring, CDI for example, but the role each of them gives to the underlying container makes them quite different.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But from your answer it is unclear why it is necessary in Spring to define some beans. In a standard JavaEE application I can inject every class I want. In Spring it could be necessary to define the Bean beforehead. Or is the "container" the answer and the only reason? I thought the Spring application context is also a sort of a container.

Comment: I'll try to clarify if I can, but as I said it is no small question. JavaEE is all about the container. There was the servlet and EJB containers, nowadays we would speak about profiles, web profile being roughly the evolution of the servlet container. But the container has an opinion on how you do things for so-called enterprise apps. The container in Spring is a DI container. It doesn't offer functionality other than wire objects based on some form of declaration: XML, then annotations and component scan, then Java configuration. It remained yours to decide which technology to wire with what.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand these principles.